# url is change when submit on button

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter my view file is

```
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-50" action="<?php base_url('Login')?>" method="post">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-33"> Account Login </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid Username is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="text"  id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username"/>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('username') ?></span>

                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 rs1 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="password"  id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="password"/>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password') ?></span>

                </div>
                <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-20">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark login100-form-btn" name="submit" value="Login"/>
                    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center p-t-45 p-b-4">
                    <span class="txt1"> Forgot  </span>
                    <a href="#" class="txt2 hov1">Username / Password? </a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <span class="txt1">Create an account?</span>
                    <a href="#" class="txt2 hov1"> Sign up</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have send post request like this url

> http://localhost/openvoips/index.php/Login

but its change into

> http://localhost/openvoips/index.php/Login?username=sanjay&password=12345&submit=Login

how to solve it

Comment: because its behavior of `GET` method in `form`. Its sending data to your controller via URL. you are access data as post metof in controller, so use POST method in form

Comment: Use `method="POST"`

Comment: change  `<div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-50" action="<?php base_url('Login')?>" method="post">` to form tag e.g,  `<form ...`

Comment: but i am sending post methed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending post method.

Try to update below codebase

```
 <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-50" action="<?php base_url('Login')?>" method="post">
        <form class="login100-form validate-form">
```

To

```
 <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-50" >
            <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="<?php base_url('Login')?>" method="post">
```